# Flask: save object with timestamp

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am doing flask app with flask-sqlalchemy.
I need to save object to db with timestamp provided by client.
For example:

```js
2017-03-03T11:30:00+04:00
```

I need to save this timestamp with +4 time zone. Model declaration looks like this:

```js
class Appointment(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'appointments'

    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_time = Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
```

So here I have start_time attribute. I try to save my appointment object like this:

```js
new_appointment = Appointment()
# at this line I convert string time to python datetime
appointment_time = datetime.strptime(string_datetime[:len(string_datetime) - 3] +                                                 string_datetime[len(string_datetime) - 2:],
                                                 '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

new_appointment.start_time = appointment_time
db.session.add(new_appointment)
db.session.commit()
```

When I check my db, my object is saved with my servers timezone (in this case as +6). I also tried to save without timezone (setting timezone=False), but again timestamp is saved as +6, but without indication of timezone. How do I force my object being saved with provided timzone?

Answer (score 1):

Use [pyTZ](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz) module

Take UTC time and convert it to desired timezone

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import *

eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2017, 10, 3, 7, 27, 0))
print loc_dt
```

Also, you can go through this interesting [article](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2015/python-and-timezones) detailing problems with the datetime timezone handling